# Perceptron Algorithm - Adjustments

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, perceptron

I am taking a data mining class at my college. I really don't understand this question. Can anyone help me understand it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The importance weight gives you an idea of how frequently you would find that specific data point when sampling. You can use that to increase the training data set. For example, if you only two data points:

```
(1, 1, 0.7)
(0, 3, 0.3)
```

That would be equivalent to having a training data set in the form:

```
(1, 1) (1, 1) (1, 1) (1, 1) (1, 1) (1, 1) (1, 1)
(0, 3) (0, 3) (0, 3)
```